# Paypal adaptive payments callers

Tags: paypal, paypal-adaptive-payments

As written in the pdf (Adaptive Payments) it is stated:

If you allow a third party to PayPal to execute an application on your behalf, the third party becomes the API caller because the party is now calling the Adaptive Payments API. The third party must also have permission from PayPal to use the advanced service. For example, if an application supports chained payments, both you and the third party must have permission to use the service.

When third party executes application on my behalf? If I own my API keys I assumed I was always the API caller. What did Paypal mean by that?

Answer (score 1):

You need to think of it as three (or more) separate parties:  Payer, Receiver(s), and the application itself.

In many cases, you will indeed be the API caller because you'll be making payments on your own behalf.  If another user grants permissions for your application to use their PayPal account, though, they will also need whatever permissions your application needs approved on their own account.

If we step outside of Adaptive Payments for a moment I can give you a better example.

PayPal Payments Pro has monthly fees, additional account vetting, and approvals that need to be made in order to use it.  If you have Payments Pro available on your PayPal account you can use your API credentials to make payments that way without any problem.  However, if somebody else is using your application and you're processing payments on their behalf with your API credentials, they would also need Payments Pro enabled on their own account, otherwise the call would fail.

Adaptive Payments is the same way.  It carries lots of special permissions that accounts need for various tasks, and even though YOU have been approved for something, that doesn't mean your users have, so you have to watch out for that.

Hope that makes sense.

Comment: Yes it does make sense, but what would be 'processing payments on their behalf with your api' then?

All I need would be chained payments where my client is first receiver and I am second (usually it is the other way as its described in the PDFs), or parallel payments with client as first receiver and again me as the second one.

Comment: And yes, I know that I sholud be the primary receiver as it's stated in the policy. That's why I'd prefer parallel payments. But that's not the point :) I am just wondering if my situation falls under the first question problem

Comment: I'm pretty sure that if your account is approved for Chained Payments you'll be just fine as long as you are also one of the receivers.

Where this would be an issue is if you built the app for other people to send payments to various users without you in the mix...but your application is still processing everything for them.  

In that sort of a scenario they would need the same permissions on their own account in order to use your application.

Comment: ok so I am stuck with the preapproval option if I want to sell items only after I confirm they are on/in stock. Stuck - because if someone wants to pay for something they have to have paypal account.

Comment: As I mentioned in your other question, it's starting to sound like maybe you don't need Adaptive Payments and you could just use Express Checkout.